# Stuck on integrals computation

Tags: integration

I'm trying to compute these two integrals:

$$\int-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\cdot e^{0.05t} \mathop{dt}$$

$$\int F\cdot\cos(0.07t)\cdot e^{0.05t}\mathop{dt}$$

I'm not sure what would be the best method to apply here. Should I go with integration by parts? If so, then what should be the variables $u$ and $v$ be here?

Comment: Are we integrating with respect to $t$? What does $F$ represent? Is $F$ a constant?

Comment: For the first one: $\sin(\pi/4)=?$

Comment: As I told you in your previous question, have a look here for the second integral: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions

Comment: So, how is it going? Did you manage?